# How to get instant match to a node, If i know it's < id >

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to speed up this query:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///path/to/file' AS line
MATCH (n:Organization{rc:'2051061'})-[:Ap]->(a:Person{numDc: toint(line[1])})
CREATE (a)-[:Af]->(n)
```

The CSV has about 100k rows, the relationship `(n:Organization)-[:Ap]->(a:Person)` is unique between different a/b pairs. The number of nodes with label `:Organization` is 50, and those with `:Person` is 200k.

So basically I take a value in the csv and check if a :Person who has a relation `:Ap` with the :Organization with the given rc (2051061) has that value as `numDc` and then I add another relation between the Person and the organization.

My query runs too slow, I even added indexes to `:Person(numDc)` and `Organization(rc)`.

So I think since I'm matching the organization for every row It may be the problem.

How can I get instant match to that node if I do know it's < id >.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: You may not actually need to create an `Af` relationship if it does not have any properties, since you can easily traverse an `Ap` relationship "backwards" from `a` to `n`.

If you really do need to create an `Af` relationship, you can improve your performance by forcing Cypher to use both of your indexes.

Using [PROFILE](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.0/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html) on your query (with the 2 indexes), I see that the Cypher planner (I tried [both planner types](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-are-queries-executed.html)) uses the `SchemaIndex` operator (which takes advantage of an index) with only **one** of your indexes. In order to force Cypher to use **both** indexes, you can use the `USING INDEX` clause, like this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///path/to/file' AS line
MATCH (n:Organization { rc:'2051061' })
USING INDEX n:Organization(rc)
MATCH (n)-[:Ap]->(a:Person { numDc: toint(line[1])})
USING INDEX a:Person(numDc)
CREATE (a)-[:Af]->(n);
```

The performance should be much improved.

Comment: Thanks import time was improved from 45 segs to 5 segs :)!

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use your own unique identifier instead of node id. Because you can't to rely on ID. Node id is basically address where node is in file with nodes records.

You can add unique id to your csv file and import it into database.

Or you can use GraphAware UUID module for creating UUID on the fly - https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid

Comment: Yeah, I still want to have quick access to a node, for each line imported in the csv, I mean having 'n' matched before reading the csv (look at my code) Instead of matching it every time.